# Editing additional info in a dataTable on primeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, javabeans

So, I have a dataTable on my page that shows some basic information and a row expansion to show the extra information. I'm trying to create a button/context menu to show a dialog so the user could edit the informations on the table (basic and extra, all in a form) but I'm having trouble in getting this data from the table. When I click the button to show the dialog, it only shows the information of the first row, and not the row I selected. Any ideas? Thank you. Code follows below.

```
 <p:dataTable id="socios" var="socio" value="#{sociosBean.socios}" rowKey="#{socio.id}"   
                         selection="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido}" selectionMode="single" paginator="true"
                         widgetVar="socios" emptyMessage="Nenhum socio encontrado " filteredValue="#{sociosBean.socioFiltro}" 
                         rows="10" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
        <p:menuitem value ="Editar" update="socios" icon ="ui-icon-search"
                    oncomplete="editar.show();">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{sociosBean.socioEditar}" value="#{socio}"/>      
        </p:menuitem>

        <p:menuitem value="Excluir" update="socios" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="excluir.show();"/>
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:outputPanel>  
                <h:outputText value="Socios" />   
            </p:outputPanel>  
        </f:facet> 

        <p:column style="width:2%">  
            <p:rowToggler />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column headerText="ID" filterMatchMode="startsWith" id="id" filterBy="#{socio.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{socio.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Nome" filterBy="#{socio.nome}" filterMatchMode="startsWith" id="colunaNome" >
            <h:outputText value="#{socio.nome}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Sexo" style="width: 4%">
            <h:outputText value="#{socio.sexo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Data de Nascimento">
            <h:outputText value="#{socio.dataNascimento}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Cargo">
            <h:outputText value="#{socio.cargo}"/>
        </p:column>


        <p:column headerText="Status">
            <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{socio.ativo}" offLabel="Inativo" onLabel="Ativo" disabled="true"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Editar">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="editar.show();">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{sociosBean.socioEditar}" value="#{socio}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>

            <p:panelGrid id ="informacao" columns="2" style="width:400px; alignment-baseline: middle" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    #{socio.nome}
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputText value="ID"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.id}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Data de Nascimento"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{socio.dataNascimento}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>

                <h:outputText value="Nome do Pai"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.nomePai}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Nome da Mãe"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.nomeMae}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Cargo"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.cargo}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Telefone"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.telefone}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Ano de Admissão"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.anoAdmissao}"/>

                <h:outputText value ="Endereço"/>
                <h:outputText value ="#{socio.endereco}"/>


            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:button href="AID.xhtml" value="Voltar"/>
    <p:confirmDialog id="excluirSocio" message="Excluir sócio?"  
                     header="Aviso" severity="alert" widgetVar="excluir">  

        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Sim" update="mensagem, socios" oncomplete="excluir.hide();"  
                         actionListener="#{sociosBean.excluirSocio()}"  icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Não" onclick="excluir.hide();" type="button" icon="ui-icon-close" />   

    </p:confirmDialog>  
    <p:dialog id="editarSocio" widgetVar="editar">
        <p:panelGrid id="cadastro" columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">Editar Sócio</f:facet>

            <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:"/>
            <p:inputText id="nome" required ="true" value ="#{sociosBean.socioEditar.nome}"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="s" value="Sexo:"/>
            <p:selectOneRadio id="s" value="#{sociosBean.socioEditar.sexo}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="m" itemLabel="Masculino"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="f" itemLabel="Feminino"/>
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:outputLabel for ="serie" value="Série:"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="serie" value="#{sociosBean.socioEditar.serie}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="3º Ensino Médio" itemValue="3EM" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="2º Ensino Médio" itemValue="2EM" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="1º Ensino Médio" itemValue="1EM" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="8º Ensino Fundamental" itemValue="8EF" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="7º Ensino Fundamental" itemValue="7EF" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="6º Ensino Fundamental" itemValue="6EF" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="5º Ensino Fundamental" itemValue="5EF" /> 

            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:outputLabel for ="endereco" value ="Endereço:"/>
            <p:inputText id ="endereco" maxlength="60" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.endereco}"/>

            <p:outputLabel for ="telefone" value ="Telefone:"/>
            <p:inputMask id="telefone"  value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.telefone}" mask="(99)9999-9999"/>
            <p:outputLabel for ="nomePai" value ="Nome do Pai:"/>
            <p:inputText id ="nomePai" maxlength="45" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.nomePai}"/>

            <p:outputLabel for ="nomeMae" value ="Nome da Mãe:"/>
            <p:inputText id ="nomeMae" maxlength="45" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.nomeMae}"/>

            <p:outputLabel for ="dataNascimento" value ="Data de nascimento: "/>
            <p:calendar id="dataNascimento" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.dataNascimento}" required="true" navigator ="true" locale ="pt" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>

            <p:outputLabel for ="cargo" value ="Cargo:"/>
            <p:inputText id ="cargo" maxlength="25" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.cargo}"/>
            <p:outputLabel for ="anoAdmissao" value ="Ano Admissão:"/>
            <p:inputMask id ="anoAdmissao" maxlength="4" mask="9999" value="#{sociosBean.socioEscolhido.anoAdmissao}"/>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="btnEditar" value="Editar" actionListener="#{sociosBean.editarSocio()}"/>

            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
    package com.beans;

import com.dao.SociosDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.hibernate.Socios;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
/**
 *
 * @author João Pedro Sacheti
 */
public class SociosBean {

    private String nome;
    private String serie;
    private char sexo;
    private String endereco;
    private String nomePai;
    private String nomeMae;
    private Date dataNascimento;
    private String cargo;
    private Integer anoAdmissao;
    private boolean ativo;
    private String telefone;
    private List<Socios> socioFiltro;
    private ArrayList<Socios> socios;
    private Socios socioEscolhido;
    private Socios socioEditar;
    //getters and setters

public SociosBean() {
    this.socios = new ArrayList<Socios>();
    this.socioEditar = new Socios();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that you are not updating the content of the dialog when you show it. So you would have to add `update="editarSocio:cadastro"` to the commandButton you use to show the dialog.
But be aware that the id you will have to enter depends on the structure of the XHTML, which I dont know.